# This jquery works in html but not in javascript file and jquery 2.1.4 file source not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this jquery code that works when i place it in the html file, but when place in a javascript file with other code it does not work.

When i use a jquery file from the site and source it to my html file it wont work (It is correctly sourced because I am using a javascript from the same folder).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min"></script>
```

As soon as i place it inside the javascript it stops working. This is the code that works (it is used exactly like the code below in javascript without the html part of course):

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            $(document).ready(function() {
  var canvas = $('#lienzo')[0];
  canvas.width = 1000;
  canvas.height = 500;


if(canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var w = canvas.width;
    var h = canvas.height;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(174,194,224,0.5)';
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';


    var init = [];
    var maxParts = 1000;
    for(var a = 0; a < maxParts; a++) {
      init.push({
        x: Math.random() * w,
        y: Math.random() * h,
        l: Math.random() * 1,
        xs: -4 + Math.random() * 4 + 2,
        ys: Math.random() * 10 + 10
      })
    }

    var particles = [];
    for(var b = 0; b < maxParts; b++) {
      particles[b] = init[b];
    }

    function draw() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
      for(var c = 0; c < particles.length; c++) {
        var p = particles[c];
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(p.x, p.y);
        ctx.lineTo(p.x + p.l * p.xs, p.y + p.l * p.ys);
        ctx.stroke();
      }
      move();
    }

    function move() {
        for(var b = 0; b < particles.length; b++) {
            var p = particles[b];
            p.x += p.xs;
            p.y += p.ys;
            if(p.x > w || p.y > h) {
              p.x = Math.random() * w;
              p.y = -20;
            }
        }
    }

    setInterval(draw, 30);

    }
});
    </script>
```

Comment: did you check console for errors

Comment: Open the browser's developer tools. Look in the Console. Are there errors? Look in the Network tab. Do you see the request for the JS file? Does it get a 200 OK response? Does it contain the content you expect?

Comment: Show us errors in console

Comment: You forgot to add `.js` at the end

Comment: `src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min"` — my crystal ball says you have a 404 error

Comment: It should be `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @Quentin I get this error when i place it in javacript "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: @EAlexisT Read my comment,  
It should be `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @Hemal Thx, that worked, but how do i make it work in a javascript file i am using??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min"></script>
```

with this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thx, that worked, but how do i make the jquery code, i posted, work in a javascript file i am using??

Comment: I found out how to make it work in a separte js file. Thanks for the help :).

Comment: Accept as answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

You might have forgotten the

> .js

, but your question isn't that clear.

Comment: Thx, that worked, but how do i make the jquery code, i posted, work in a javascript file i am using??

Comment: You can put it in a file (myFile.js) and then - after jquery - <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myFile.js"></script>